# Expression simplifying after differentiation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm doing some textbook differentiation questions. After the differentiation is complete the expression looks like this:

$3{(5x+1)}^2(5){(3-2x)}^4+{(5x+1)}^3(4){(3-2x)}^3(-2)$

Which is also what I get. It is then simplified to this:

${(5x+1)}^2{(3-2x)}^3[15(3-2x)-8(5x+1)]$

Is this correct or this there an error in the textbook? I can't figure it out

Comment: hint: $ ab+ac=a(b+c)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct. Both the terms in the first expression have the factor $(5x+1)^2(3-2x)^3$. Factoring this out, the expression looks like follows: $${(5x+1)}^2{(3-2x)}^3[3\cdot 5(3-2x)+(5x+1)\cdot 4\cdot (-2)]$$ $$={(5x+1)}^2{(3-2x)}^3[15(3-2x)-8(5x+1)]$$

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me. Expand the two expressions and see if they are both the same.